# Why is my iferror function not working in this case?

Tags: excel, vba

Why is my `IFERROR` function not working? I just want it to return "NOT DONKEYS" if the `vlookup` returns the error 2024 or #NA.

I have tried merging the two lines together by replacing the "QUANTITY" in the `IFERROR` line with the whole `vlookup` function but it still doesn't help. I only have the one workbook open, that's why I don't refer to any workbook in the code. The range for `vlookup` is only a list of fruits and it doesn't have "DONKEY" as an option.

```vb
Sub FRUITS()
    Dim QUANTITY As Variant

   'find quantity of fruits
    QUANTITY = Application.VLookup("DONKEY", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("FRUITS"), 2, False)

    'return "NO DONKEYS" if QUANTITY returns #NA error
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 5).Value = IfError(QUANTITY, "NO DONKEYS")
End Sub
```

I expect the `IFERROR` function to return "NO DONKEYS" into cell (5,5) if `vlookup` runs into an error.

Comment: vba does not have `IfError` you will need to do your own IF with `IsError` or put `Application.` in front.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 5).Value = IIF(IsError(Quantity), "No Donkeys", Quantity)`

Comment: If that code compiles, you're missing `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different way of trapping `#NA` errors on `VLOOKUP`, using `If IsError` or `If Not IsError`.

***Modified Code***

```
Sub FRUITS()

' Dim QUANTITY As Variant

If Not IsError(Application.VLookup("DONKEY", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("FRUITS"), 2, False)) Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 5).Value = Application.VLookup("DONKEY", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("FRUITS"), 2, False) ' find quantity of fruits
Else ' in case VLOOKUP doesn't find a match
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 5).Value = "NO DONKEYS" 'return "NO DONKEYS" if QUANTITY returns #NA error
End If

End Sub
```

Note: you could wrap it up using a `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` in the beginning of this `If`, or just set a `Worksheet` object.

Comment: No need to call vlookup twice.

Comment: @GSerg depends on how you use it, with the way I use it you kind a must, or am I too tired today ?

Comment: You probably are; you can save the result into `QUANTITY` just like the OP did, test that for `IsError` and assign it to the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Quick one line IF that replaces the error with `NO DONKEYS`

```
Sub FRUITS()
    Dim QUANTITY As Variant

   'find quantity of fruits
    QUANTITY = Application.VLookup("DONKEY", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("FRUITS"), 2, False)

    'return "NO DONKEYS" if QUANTITY returns #NA error
    If IsError(QUANTITY) Then QUANTITY = "NO DONKEYS"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 5).Value = QUANTITY
End Sub
```

Comment: Curious about the result, not as far as # of lines of code, but bench-mark wise. If you were to test 100,000 records, where most records `VLOOKUP` was successful, then your code would run 3 lines of code per line of data (reading from sheet to Variant and then writing it back), while mine only runs 2.

Comment: @ShaiRado The `vlookup` call is 99.99% of the execution time. This code makes a vlookup call once per line. Your code makes a vlookup call once per unsuccessful line and twice per successful line. If, like you are saying, most of the records are successful, your code is 2 times slower.

Comment: @GSerg thanks for that key piece of data, I will definitely take it into consideration from now on :)

Comment: @shai when you are concerned about performance,  the best answer is always: _test it_.